# Writing data.text file using a column "delimiter"

Tags: python

I want to write a file.txt with data in Python in an appropriate format. Look the following code (it's just an example of my real code, which is more complex in the numeric part)

```
import numpy as np


list_values_r = [0.1,1.0]

points = 10
final_time = 10.0
steep = final_time/points 
time_list = np.arange(0.0,final_time,steep) #list of the time variable


f1 = open("data_file.txt", "w")


for i in list_values_r:
    count = 0
    while (count<points):
        t = time_list[count]
        f1.write(str(t) + " "+str(t**2-5*i)+"\n")
        count +=1



f1.close()
```

Using this I obtain the following set of data

```
0.0 -0.5
1.0 0.5
2.0 3.5
3.0 8.5
4.0 15.5
5.0 24.5
6.0 35.5
7.0 48.5
8.0 63.5
9.0 80.5
0.0 -5.0
1.0 -4.0
2.0 -1.0
3.0 4.0
4.0 11.0
5.0 20.0
6.0 31.0
7.0 44.0
8.0 59.0
9.0 76.0
```

But the thing that I want obtain is four columns of data (2 columns for each iteration in the loop), so this:

```
0.0 -0.5 0.0 -0.5
1.0 0.5 1.0 -4.0
2.0 3.5 2.0 -1.0
3.0 8.5 3.0 4.0
4.0 15.5 4.0 11.0
5.0 24.5 5.0 20.0
6.0 35.5 6.0 31.0
7.0 48.5 7.0 44.0
8.0 63.5 8.0 59.0
9.0 80.5 9.0 76.0
```

The point is that probably must be exist some delimiter like "\n" in order to start to write in another column and not in the following line, someone know how can be done it? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like the delimiter for another column is just `' '`, no?

Comment: why not simply use [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) numpy function: `numpy.savetxt(fname, X, fmt='%.18e', delimiter=' ', newline='\n', header='', footer='', comments='# ')[source]`?

Comment: Seams reasonable, but I don't understand, how can be used this inside the loop while? can you put an example  using my code please?